# Is it possible to reshape with one unknown dimension in Wolfram?

Tags: list-manipulation

In Python I can reshape array remaining one dimension unknown, allowing Python to infer it automatically:

```
A=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
np.reshape(A, (2,-1))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Is the same possible in Mathematica?

**UPDATE**

In Python I can set any dimension to `-1`, not only last, for example

```
A = np.array(range(3*4*5))
np.reshape(A, (3, -1, 5))
```

apparently, `reshape` function calculates product of explicit dimensions and divides total length by it to compute unknown dimension. In Mathematica I can do this explicitly

```
A = Range[3*4*5]
ArrayReshape[A, {3, Length[A]/3/5, 5}]
```

but can I do as in Python?

---

*EDIT: I reckon a better way to pose this question is to ask:*

**How can I implement similar functionality in Mathematica, preferably in a general way?**

Comment: Use `Partition`.

Comment: To elaborate on @Alan's comment, `a = Range[6]; Partition[a, 3]` will give you your output. [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) also has a lot of arguments you can play around with to generate more complex lists from your input.

Comment: @Alan can I do all other things with `Partition`?

Comment: No, to have a function of equal generality you must implement it yourself.